# Leaflet playback place marker

Tags: leaflet

I am using the playback plugin and i am using it on an image overlay.

https://github.com/hallahan/LeafletPlayback

I need to scale the floor map before placing the marker. with the plugin the marker is placed some where outside of the floor map.

I am able to solve the issue for GPS tracking, where i have written a function to scale the map and place the marker inside pointToLayer method of layer property.

I want to do the same for marker too. any help is appreciated.

```
const playbackOptions = {

    playControl: true,
    dateControl: true,
    orientIcons: true,
    fadeMarkersWhenStale: true,
      // layer and marker options
    layer: {
      pointToLayer(featureData, latlng) {
        const { lat, lng } = latlng;
        let result = {};

        if (featureData && featureData.properties && featureData.properties.path_options) {
          result = featureData.properties.path_options;
        }

        if (!result.radius) {
          result.radius = 5;
        }

        const scaleX = width / details.width;
        const scaleY = height / details.length;
        const m = {
          x: lat * scaleX,
          y: lng * scaleY,
        };
        const iconCls = 'asset-icon';
        const item = L.marker(self.map.unproject([m.x, m.y], self.map.getMaxZoom()), {
          icon: makeMarker(iconCls, 0),
          opacity: 0.9,
          type: 'asset',
          lat,
          lng,
        });
        item.bindTooltip(`<p>${lat}, ${lng}`, { className: 'asset-label', offset: [0, 0] });

        return item;
      }
    },

    marker: {
      getPopup(featureData) {
        let result = '';

        if (featureData && featureData.properties && featureData.properties.title) {
          result = featureData.properties.title;
        }

        return result;
      }
    }

  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve actual GPS coordinates, it would probably be easier to actually do the reverse, i.e. to *georeference* your image overlay once for good, instead of trying to fiddle with the geographic coordinates of each of the feature you try to show relatively to your image.